# Conversation is not working without any errors in grammyjs

Tags: bots, node-telegram-bot-api, telegraph, grammy

I have a problem with Conversation. I wrote the following code in Conversation:

```
if (ctx.session.in_conversation == true) return;
    conversation.session.in_conversation = true;

    await ctx.replyWithChatAction("typing");
    await ctx.reply("Mahsulot nomini kiriting:", {
      reply_markup: cancelKeyboard,
    });
    const nameMsg = await conversation.waitFor(["message"], {
      otherwise: () => ctx.reply("Iltimos matn ko'rinishida kiriting!"),
    });
    const name = nameMsg.message?.text;
    if (name == "❌ Bekor qilish") {
      conversation.session.in_conversation = false;
      await ctx.reply("‍♂️ Amal bekor qilindi", { reply_markup: mainKeyboard });
      return;
    }

    await ctx.reply("Mahsulot haqida ma'lumot:");
    const descryptionMsg = await conversation.waitFor(["message"]);
    let descryption = descryptionMsg.message.text;

    await ctx.reply(`${descryption}`);

    conversation.session.in_conversation = false;
    return;
```

Conversation is stopping by itself without returning any error.

```
await ctx.reply("Mahsulot haqida ma'lumot:");
```

The text has been sent and the conversation is stuck. Where did I go wrong?

All are working until 2nd reply. But nothing is working after that. replies, conversation logs ... nothing. I solved the previous ones by completely deleting the conversation or rebuilding the project from 0.